# Select a child node in XML with specific name using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to find a child element with tag name Reason.
I have XML doc that is basically contains bunch of elements with Entity name.
Reason tag is somewhere inside of Entity(along with other elements).

```
void IParseResponse.ParseResponseData(XmlDocument responseDocument)
{
    List<string> reasons = new List<string>();
    var reasonValue = "";
    var entityList = responseDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Entity");

    if (entityList != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode reason in entityList)
        {   
            reasonValue = //look into current Entity element, find Reason in it and get it's inner text.
            reasons.Add(reasonValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This is location of Reason element.

```
<Entity>
  <WatchList>
     <Match ID="1">
        <MatchDetails>
          <Reason>
```

Does anybody have experience with this?

Comment: What is reasonList? Do you mean entityList?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can get all the `Reason` elements.

```
var xml = "<Entity> <WatchList><Match ID=\"1\"><MatchDetails><Reason>asdasd</Reason></MatchDetails></Match></WatchList></Entity>";

var x = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var reasons = x.Descendants("Reason").ToList();
foreach (var reason in reasons)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reason.Value);
}
```

If you give us a more complete example of your XML I can improve the answer.

**Edit:**

If you want to use XmlDocument instead you could do this:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = responseDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Reason");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nodes[i].InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. :) I do not have xml document in string form it comes as XmlDocument. Should I maybe do conversion from XmlDocument to XDocument? @Nasreddine

Comment: Using `XDocument` makes it much easier to parse XML. You can load the Xml from XmlDocument to XDocument using this : `XDocument.Parse(responseDocument.InnerXml);`